# Why does photos app on Mac complain about insufficient disk space?

Tags: macos

I am trying to backup photos from my iphone onto it. Photos app complains about insufficient disk space of 7.7 GB even though I have 40 GB of free space. How should i tackle this problem?

Comment: see what app is pointing to for storage space and change that as perhaps you have that pointing to a smaller location with less space than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message is the same as the one from other Apple apps, the message means that you need 7.7 GB more free space than the amount you presently have, not that you need 7.7 GB of free space.